# What do I do with a branch after merging it?

Tags: git, gitlab

We use Git for creating documentation, along with Gitlab. I have a branch, `shannon`, that I created from the `master` branch. They're tracking remote branches with the same names.

My typical workflow looks like this:

1. Do work on my project on `shannon`
2. Commit my work to local `shannon`
3. Push finished work to remote `origin/shannon`
4. Create a merge request on Gitlab from `shannon` to `master`

After the merge is completed, I currently keep the `shannon` branch alive.

I usually pull `origin/master` into `shannon` after creating and closing a merge request, just to keep my branch up to date.

This creates the typical *merged master into shannon from < url >* commit that is then visible in future merge requests.

Am I doing this right? Should I instead be deleting `shannon` after a successful merge request and recreating it when I start work again?

I really appreciate any help you can give me! Maybe there's a way to make my workflow more efficient.

Comment: I suggest always creating a fresh new branch from `master` every time you start a new feature.  If you reuse `shannon` this way, it will have an ugly history, with many merge cycles in it.

Comment: It currently does and it's pretty ugly. I'm the only one on the team using branches at the present, everyone else is pushing to `master` so I keep having to merge it in. I will start deleting and recreating `shannon`. I should delete both the local and remote `shannon` branches, correct?

Answer (score 1):

- All other things you are doing is fine but, all the time for new feature try to make a new branch for both local and remote and keep both feature branch in sync.
- Keep local and remote master in sync and create branch from master.
- In gitlab there is a option with merge request `delete branch on merge`. You can use that so you need not to worry about deleting manually.
- Also make sure the if someone join your team and you are working on same master than in your practice add to take a pull then push to remote branch to prevent any merge issues.